# API not properly registering CosmosDB dependencies to App Insights

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I have an API hosted on Azure services that sends Logs to Application Insights. Since I'm using CosmosDB, I'm using the automatic configurations that come from the **Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore** NuGet package.

My problem is, while local debugging:

- Each first API request (after starting the service) that requires access to the CosmosDB account registers the correct **dependency** type logs.
- Any posterior request of the same type, even if it's the same request, doesn't register the dependencies, only the **request** type log is registered
- For the time the API is running, it keeps registering "ghost" dependencies from the first request, that should've been stopped.
- I've checked configurations in the settings' json, the AppInsights_InstrumentationKey and LogLevels are correct.

My task is to fix this and leave everything automatically done without custom telemetry, and then apply changes to the deployed version. Any help is very well welcomed!

Comment: Are you connecting using [Gateway or Direct mode?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/conceptual-resilient-sdk-applications#connectivity-modes)

Comment: @PeterBons I had to research on that because I'm still a bit inexperienced and didn't know about that. From what I checked, it seems to be Gateway mode. I also discovered that the "ghost" dependencies are perfectly timed at 5mins apart from each other. That leads me to believe there's something still running on a schedule and hanging to that 1st request.

Comment: Those 5mins apart requests are normal, it is a kind of background ping to/check of the gateway servers .

Comment: Please make sure you are using gateway mode. The default is Direct mode. Direct mode uses TCP, not http and hence is not logged by application insights (unless the preview version of the AI Nuget is used)

Comment: If I was using Direct mode (which is TCP, and according to Microsoft's documentation, TCP isn't an automatic logged dependency), could the 1st request still log the dependencies while following ones won't? I also noticed there's no mode configuration in the project's code, so that can real mean it's direct mode. I'll try to configure it to be Gateway and check what happens

Comment: Even in direct mode some calls are done using https, only those will be logged.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense actually. This is quite helpful to me, I believe that can be the way to fix this. Thanks for so much help!! I'll do some changes based on this and test.

Comment: @PeterBons it was on Direct mode indeed. I configured it to be Gateway mode and it now registers the dependencies for each request. Thanks so much for the help, I surely had to learn a bit more!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, those 5mins apart requests are normal, it is a kind of background ping to/check of the backend servers.

When connecting to Cosmos DB you have two options, [gateway mode and direct mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/conceptual-resilient-sdk-applications#connectivity-modes). The default is Direct mode. Direct mode uses TCP, not http and hence is not logged by application insights. Unless the [preview version of Cosmos SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos/3.33.0-preview) is used, see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-dependencies#automatically-tracked-dependencies):

> Tracked automatically if HTTP/HTTPS is used. TCP will also be captured automatically using preview package >= 3.33.0-preview.